# Search a location within specific city Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am little familiar with google maps
I can implement a search like [Google Maps Link1: Search Box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox), but this time i need a search within a specific city only. Have a look at this [Google Maps Link2: Drop Down lists. Country, Area(State), City](http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/Locate-city-on-Google-Maps-tutorial/google-maps.php)

My Desired Reult

I need only an example link where user can Select Country, Select City like link2 then search a location(town/colony/place/location/spot) in textbox like link 2. And this search should produce 0 or more results only **within that particular city**. However it would be be even better if i could be guided about the implementation

I have tried to search out google like

1. search a location within a city google maps
2. search town vs city google maps
3. search within specific city google maps

But i am stuck to find any example like that.
Edit: A town(location, place, spot) with a city means

**Upadte** : By example of location/spot is **Creme De La Crepe**, London, United Kingdom

Or

**Transport Museum**, London, United Kingdom

If i search for `Transport Museum` when i have selected london. Map would take me to `London Transport Museum`

Comment: You want to find a town within a city? _Select City like link2 then search a location(town/colony)_

Comment: I thought they were the same but only a different size. What is a town in a city to you? Can you give an example.

Comment: I have added exapmles

Comment: Ok, so you mean a specific location, not a town. A town is a city but smaller.

Comment: Yes I think it is clear now